# Invertible solution to underdetermined system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, control-theory

Given an underdetermined system of linear equations like

$$
a X = b \tag{1}
$$

with $a \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ where $a$ and $b$ are given and $X$ is the matrix of unknowns. For $n > 1$, the system is clearly underdetermined, since only $n$ equations exist for $n^2$ unknowns. So, either none or infinitely many solutions exist.

Of course, a straightforward way to find some solution is to use the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse like $X = a^{\dagger} b$.

However, I am only interested in "invertible solutions". That is a solution to $(1)$ such that $X^{-1}$ exists. For my problem, I know that such a solution always exists, however I also want to explicitly compute it.

I know that I can add some multiple of the nullspace of $a$ to the solution to get a new solution. However, how can I select this multiple such that the solution is guaranteed to be invertible?

Currently I add a random multiple of the nullspace in a loop until the solution is invertible. But that is of course not a nice way to do this.

**Question**: Is there a general way to find "invertible solutions" to $(1)$?

**Example**: Take as an example

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_{a} X = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_{b}
$$

Now one possible solution is given by the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse:

$$
X_1 = a^\dagger b = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So we have $a X_1 = b$ but unfortunatly $X_1^{-1}$ does not exist. If we use however instead

$$
X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

we have again $a X_2 = b$ as required but this time $X_2^{-1}$ does exist. But how to find such a solution in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this not as a system of equations but rather a unknown linear map with transformation matrix $X$ such that $X^Ta^T=b^T$.

First we construct a basis of the domain $B_1=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{n-1},a^T\}$ and the image $B_1=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1},b^T\}$. It doesnt matter how it looks apart from $a^T$ and $b^T$ being basis vectors. (Obviously we need $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$, see remark below)

Then we can simply calculate the transformation matrix by the standard procedure of elementary column operations to obtain the identity matrix.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & \ldots u_{n-1} & a^T \\
\hline
v_1 & v_2 & \ldots v_{n-1} & b^T 
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n\\\hline
X^T 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For your special example this would read:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
5 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which yields $$X=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Remark 1: Obviously you will get a different result for another choice of your basis.

Remark 2: If $a=0$ xor $b=0$ there exists no invertible $X$. If $a=b=0$ any invertible matrix will to the trick.

Remark 3: You can omit the transpositions and calculate with row vectors and elementary row operations, that was just my personal preference...

Remark 4: Probably the easiest way is to take the canonical basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and replace one of the vectors $e_k$ by $a^T$ like I did in the example. It will always work as long as $e_k\cdot a^T\neq0$.

Comment: Amazing, just implemented it as an algorithm and it works just as I need it [Bounty needs 16 hours more to wait unfortunatly]. The nice thing is also compared to the random algorithm (apart from the fact that it is deterministic now and will always work) that it keeps the $X$ matrix relatively sparse. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding remark 4: I think the following should also work without having to check for $e_k a^T \neq 0$ (thats how I implemented it, because then its basically just a one-liner): $$
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{ker}(a) & a^T \\
\hline
\text{ker}(b) & b^T
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
I_n \\
\hline
X^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @SampleTime: No worries, I am happy to help. :-) Yes, your choice will work as well since $a^T\notin \ker(a)$. The only thing you need to ensure is that both are a basis. I guess whats easiest depends on your choice of programming language. If $\ker$ is readily available and not too time consuming it's a good option. Notice, though that you lose some control over the sparsity of $X$.